# ProductDetails.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The tutorial that I'm going off of is outdated I'm sure. I ran into this error `ProductDetails.js:27`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
```

This is my code for that line `ProductDetails.js:27` is the dispatch, alert, error, match.params.id:

```
            import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react'
            import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap'
            
            import Loader from '../layout/Loader'
            import MetaData from '../layout/MetaData'
            
            import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'
            import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
            import { getProductDetails, clearErrors } from '../../actions/productActions'
            
            const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
            
                const dispatch = useDispatch();
                const alert = useAlert();
            
                const { loading, error, product } = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
            
                useEffect(() => {
                    dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id))
                
                    if(error) {
                        alert.error(error);
                        dispatch(clearErrors())
                    }
                
                }, [dispatch, alert, error, match.params.id])
            
            
            
            export default ProductDetails
```

Not sure how much of the ProductDetails.js code but here it is, I left out my return function since it said my post was mostly code. Also posted below is my App.js code:

```
        import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"
    
    import Header from './components/layout/Header'
    import Footer from './components/layout/Footer'
    
    import Home from './components/Home'
    import ProductDetails from './components/product/ProductDetails'
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <div className="container container-fluid">
             <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home /> } exact />
              <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails /> } exact />
             </Routes>
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: The `match` prop is undefined. Where and how is this `ProductDetails` component being rendered and what props are passed to it? Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: The ProductDetails is being rendered in my App.js:

Comment: Since you reference a line number in your code, it may be helpful to point out which line is #27.

Comment: Line 27 is right after  useEffect(() => {
           This line -->         dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id))

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth the `useParams` hook hasn't changed since its introduction in `react-router-dom@5` when React introduced hooks.

The issue is that `match` is simply undefined and/or not explicitly passed as a prop to this `ProductDetails` component. If you are using `const params = useParams()` and `params` as  dependency then this very well likely is the cause of render looping as `params` will be a new object reference each render cycle. You should instead reference the `id` param directly.

I suggest also splitting up the effects into two separate effects so `getProductDetails` isn't dispatched because `error` updated, and vice-versa.

Example:

```
const ProductDetails = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();

  const { id } = useParams();

  const { loading, error, product } = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
    }
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, alert, error]);

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I seem to be getting the same loading loop. It's now saying  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found

Comment: @Dave2K That seems like a server issue then. How are you running the app, and what are the exact reproduction steps?

Comment: I'm using MERN stack, and postman to run the app

Comment: @Dave2K That doesn't answer my question. "MERN" is what you are using, and postman doesn't run any apps, it tests endpoints. A 404 from the server is a valid response, the server didn't find the requested resource. This appears to be unrelated to this post regarding accessing the route path params.

Comment: Sorry I guess I misunderstood the question, still new to coding in general.  What exactly do you mean by how am I running the app?

Comment: @Dave2K Like when you run `npm run start` to build and serve a development build of the app locally. Can you clarify what request is being made to the server that is returning a 404 error?